# How to obtain the previous and next value of the max and min in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to find the previous and next valor of the max valor and min valor in a dataframe, ive tried this:

```
for name, group in df[df["air"] == False].groupby("id"):
    maxTime= group["timestamp"].rolling(1).max()
```

The problem its that this gave me value in float and im not even sure if its the next valor of the max.

And the other:

```
for name, group in df[df["air"] == False].groupby("id"):
    maxTime= group["timestamp"].rolling(-1).min()
```

Im not shure if this works because of the -1.

Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                   "air": (True, False, False, True, False, False),
                   "timestamp": (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)}
                  )
```

For example:
for id -> a max would be 3 and the previous would be 2, the same for a the min its 1 and the next its 2.

Comment: Pleas share a sample of the dataframe, and expected value. And it's `value` not `valor`

Comment: @yatu added the dataframe, its a simplification of the real one!

Comment: Share the expected dataframe too please

Comment: @yatu i just expected the value that i gave you in the example!